# How can I update label through -textvariable

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I've typed such script:

```
set cmakeBinName "noname"
proc Get_CMakeBin { } {
    set cmakeBinName [ tk_getOpenFile -initialdir / ]
}
label .l  -text { CMake bin: }
label .lb -width 24 -textvariable $cmakeBinName
button .cmb -text "..." -command Get_CMakeBin
grid .l .lb .cmb
```

but text in label does not changes after dialog has finished.
How can I improve script?

Answer (score 4):

The variables in procedures are local unless *explicitly* stated otherwise. Try this:

```
proc Get_CMakeBin { } {
    global cmakeBinName
    set cmakeBinName [ tk_getOpenFile -initialdir / ]
}
```

You also should be aware that the `-textvariable` option takes a variable *name*, not the *contents*. You should write this:

```
label .lb -width 24 -textvariable cmakeBinName
```